# Android google play location service

Tags: android, location, android-location

When using LocationRequest.setInterval(30000), the onLocationChanged is called immediately. I want to actually get the first location update after 30 secs. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

create your own onLocationChanged Listener and set it to wait for 30s from the starting of your app.

Comment: use a handler, call handler.postDelayed with a runnable that does it in 30 seconds